# Docker image unable to build when solution is open in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

When I attempt to build a Docker image from any of my .NET core projects, if the project's solution file is open in Visual Studio 2017, the Docker build process immediately fails when attempting to create the build context:

`ERROR: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF`

If I close the solution, the Docker build succeeds.  I assume there is some kind of file locking being done by VS 2017 here that is interfering with Docker creating the build context.  Is there something I can add to a `.dockerignore` file to allow the image build to run while the solution file is open?

I did not previously encounter this problem with `project.json`-style solutions - I only started getting it once I upgraded these solutions to the new `.csproj` format in 2017.

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue? I'm experience something similar and not sure why. Other topics suggest virus checkers, but I don't think this is the case for me.  Initially it worked, but now it doesn't.  It is a strange one.

Answer (score 4):

After some experimentation I noticed this was associated with my "SQL Server" database project (.csproj)

Visual Studio tends to lock certain files which causes issues for the docker build process, it's possible to confirm this by closing visual studio, and then using powershell and running the docker build command manually for your dockerfile.

There also appears to add an extra process before it starts to execute your dockerfile, copying all the project files into a cache first, regardless of if you need those or not, or even if you intentionally specified for those files to be copied directly within your dockerfile script.

Your solution directory (not shown in the visual studio file explorer) should already have the .dockerignore file created automatically, any files that visual studio locks can be safely added into this file, for my example I added the following two lines to get the build working again;

**/*.dbmdl

**/*.jfm

At first glance, the error message listed as a result of this is not easy to interpret, it lists all the files within the solution as having issues, when in reality the first problem it encounters causes a splurge of errors.

It's also worth noting that certain virus checkers may also cause similar errors, and you will need to create exception rules within those programs.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me solve this error:
error msg="Can't add file \\?\C:\APP\wea. to tar: archive/tar: missed writing 32 bytes.

my docker build process was also hanging because of introducing a large folder 9+gigs -- had to remove this "copy" from the dockerfile.

Next: I had to close visual studio and restart docker desktop.

This solved the issue.